# Real-time conditional rendering in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to figure out how to render a component based on a bool. But the user will also have the option to change the bool and I need the app to update in real-time.

For simplicity at the moment I am trying to render some text only:

```
const deposit = <Text>deposit</Text>
const noDeposit = <Text>noDeposit</Text>
```

And this is my view where I want to render it:

```
<View>
  {this.props.depositRequired ? deposit : noDeposit}
</View>
```

It works with displaying one of them when the app is first started. But it never updates and I'm kind of at a loss of how to do this. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Share the whole component code if you can.

Comment: Right now that is the whole component code, in the end it will just be a TextInput field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use lifecycle method for receiving props called `componentWillReceiveProps` to make the component update. Implement it like this:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.depositRequired !== this.props.depositRequired){
    // just call to update the component
    this.setState({})
  }
}
```

Comment: To be honest I'm not too sure how this works, it's probably a good thing for me to read up on which I definitely will. So you have still helped me, although this is not the correct answer. I actually fixed it myself, and it was a very dumb reason. It was: ```{this.state.depositRequired ? deposit : noDeposit}``` instead of ```{this.props.depositRequired ? deposit : noDeposit```